# Is it appropriate to prohibit an adversary from querying a specific input in an algorithm in some situation?

Tags: public-key, provable-security

There are two algorithms in my framework, $E_1(\cdot)$ and $E_2(\cdot)$.

In particular, executing $E_1(\cdot)$ on a specific input $x$ (i.e., $E_1(x)$) is equivalent to executing $E_2(y)$ for some input $y$.

Suppose the security model of this framework allows an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ to query $E_1(\cdot)$ with any input, and resists $\mathcal{A}$ from querying $E_2(\cdot)$ algorithm.

Can I prevent the adversary from querying $E_1(x)$ in my security proof?

Comment: What is $B$? Explain

Comment: @kodlu sorry, I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly define a security model that prohibits certain inputs. For example the [adaptive chosen ciphertext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_chosen-ciphertext_attack) model (e.g. [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack/adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_(IND-CCA1,_IND-CCA2))) only allows an adversary to submit inputs to the decryption function that are not equal to the challenge ciphertext.

This says nothing about how useful such a model is in terms of approximating adversary capability.

Comment: Thank you. However, such input value is defined during performing E_1 algorithm (a randomness). In other words, I can't define it in the security model

Comment: If the input is randomised, then you should be able to make an argument that the adversary evaluating $E_1(x)$ is vanishingly unlikely (if it isn't than there probably is an attack).

Comment: Ok I understood Thank you